# Flutter - How to change images in another widget with a button?

Tags: flutter

I wish to change an image with other images when a corresponding button is pressed. How can I do this?

I have tried to create a variable which contains a list of images and my intent was to use an index to locate the desired image and then render the new image in the car.dart file.

(Basically The user gets to choose the wheels on their car.)

Eventually I would have lots of wheels to choose from so that's my logic behind using a list and it's index.

I'm open to other suggestions.

So far I have:

Main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './car.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            car(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: null,
                child: Text('Wheel 1')),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: null,
                child: Text('Wheel 2')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

car.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class car extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return carState();
  }
}

class carState extends State<car> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var wheelImage = [
      Image.asset('assets/wheel1.png'),
      Image.asset('assets/wheel2.png'),
    ];
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Image.asset('assets/golf.png'), //car
        wheelImage[0], //wheel
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried to use onPressed: setState but I just kept getting errors. Buttons are null for now because I have no idea how to move forward.

I'm really unsure about the best way to go about this.

I would be very grateful for the help and I'm sorry if this seems like a really moronic question... I'm new to the flutter scene.

Comment: Ok you are mentioning `MyAppState` button will change the image on `carState`'s `wheelImage` index?

Comment: I think you should consider using any state managment, like provider. https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Yes I had hoped I could use a setState in the onPressed of the MyAppState to change the wheelImage index.

Comment: @HüseyinGözübenli my head exploded looking at that link. Are there any guides to really dumb it down for me?

Comment: First time it may look hard , but keep practicing with `provider` it will help you on long run, and then go for `riverpod` then `bloc` I prefer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an int variable to have and pass selected index on `car` class and update the images. And use on `car` class like `widget.intSlectedIndex`. Also, you can learn more about state management for future .

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            car(
              intSlectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedIndex = 0;
                  });
                },
                child: Text('Wheel 1')),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedIndex = 1;
                  });
                },
                child: Text('Wheel 2')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class car extends StatefulWidget {
  final int intSlectedIndex;

  const car({Key? key, required this.intSlectedIndex}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return carState();
  }
}

class carState extends State<car> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var wheelImage = [
      Image.asset('assets/images/p7_image_asset.jpeg'),
      Image.asset('assets/images/p8_image_asset.jpeg'),
    ];
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Image.asset('assets/images/p9_image_asset.jpeg'), //car
        wheelImage[widget.intSlectedIndex], //wheel
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This extra int variable worked out great. thank you so much. I will try my best to keep learning and moving forward.

Comment: Best of luck on programmer path.

Comment: Thank you. How would I go about this if I wanted to have my buttons in a different file. Like how I have my car built in a different file. The variable we have just created wouldn't work in the same way right?

Comment: It will work the same way became it is passing as parameter , try it.